# Autogenerated LiquidXML Code Registration.iRegistrationIndicator = 0; Cause Error

Tags: c#, xsd, com, liquid-xml

I have 2 different XSDs that I have used Liquid to generate C# code and projects. Ive added them into a COM wrapper solution and call from the COM project. It all works great if I Only call one of the auto generated projects (XSDs), once I have finished one project(processing the XSD-form) and want to call the next form it fails on the following code in init:

```
Hogia.No.Liquid.Schema4166.melding4166Lib.Registration.iRegistrationIndicator = 0; 
// causes registration to take place
```

And to get any of the forms to work again. I have to reset the project/application.

If I jump over the row in debug mode all runs fine.
It does not matter which form I start to use. The same issue occur.

```
Error msg: TypeInitializationException: Ett undantagsfel uppstod for typinitieraren for 
Hogia.No.Liquid.Schema4685.melding4685Lib.Registration.
```

We have full license bought in December 2017.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: more tags and formatting

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to create a 'Super Schema' which will include or import all of your top level schema, and generate just one library.

Please see the knowledge base article: [Liquid XML Data Binder - Super Schema](http://support.liquid-technologies.com/kb/a80/super-schema.aspx)